# Get an error Remove-Item : Cannot bind parameter 'ErrorAction' after deactivating conda environment

Tags: powershell, python, anaconda

Windows 7, Anaconda 2019.10, python 3.11.0 hcf16a7b_0_cpython conda-forge.

After activating the env and then deactivating in powershell it I get this error:

```
Remove-Item : Cannot bind parameter 'ErrorAction'. Cannot convert value 'Ignore' to type 'System.Man
agement.Automation.ActionPreference" due to invalid enum values. Specify one of the following list values
clear and try again. The following enumeration values ​​are possible: "SilentlyContinue, Stop, Continue, Inquire".
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\pcraster\etc\conda\deactivate.d\gdal-deactivate.ps1:1 pos:39
+ remove-item ENV:GDAL_DATA -ErrorAction <<<<  Ignore
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Remove-Item], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CannotConvertArgumentNoMessage,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.RemoveItemCommand

Same error for position 46
```

What should I fix here?

Comment: Can we see your command?

Comment: conda deactivate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `gdal-deactivate.ps1`, replace all `-ErrorAction Ignore` with `-ErrorAction SilentlyContinue`

The "Ignore" error action was added in a later version of powershell/.net

Comment: Thanks, it worked for me well.